# Handling sparse arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create a sparse array in Swift. I'm not sure if the problem is in my declaration (no syntax errors detected) or possibly a bug in beta 2?

I am trying to declare an array of 24 class instances as optionals. I then can fill in slots of the array as necessary. Here is the declaration:

```
var usage = WaterUsage?[](count:24, repeatedValue:nil)
```

This gets through the Xcode 6 beta 2 compiler without error. The intention is to end up with an array of 24 "WaterUsage" classes all set to nil.

When I try to set an array element:

```
usage[hour] = usage
```

where hour is < 24 I get the error:

> *"WaterUsage doesn't have a member named subscript"*

I've also tried using generics but that doesn't appear to work either.

I find the Swift syntax for using optionals in complex data structures is a little obscure and could use some advice here.

Comment: your code doesn't actually read `usage[hour] = usage`, does it? if so I could see that being a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That way of defining the array is giving you an Optional array of Optional values ( `WaterUsage?[]?` ), which you have to unwrap before you can use. I think you want just the values to be optional: `WaterUsage?[]`. One way I've been able to do that is by using the generic `Array` syntax:

```
var usage: WaterUsage?[] = Array<WaterUsage?>(count:24, repeatedValue:nil)
usage[hour] = something
```

Another way is to force unwrapping of the return value of your initial declaration. I don't know why, but  `WaterUsage?[]()` has an Optional return value.

```
var usage = (WaterUsage?[](count:24, repeatedValue:nil))!
usage[hour] = something
```

Comment: Tried both and got the same error. Also tried unwrapping usage before the subscript and also got the same error

Comment: <code>import Foundation

class DayUsage
{
    var usage = WaterUsage?[](count:24, repeatedValue:nil)
    
    func addInterval(hour:Int, usage:WaterUsage?)
    {
        if (hour >= 0 && hour < 24) {
            usage![hour] = usage
        }
    }
}</code>

Comment: I think the parameter `usage` is overriding the instance variable `usage`. Rename the parameter?

Comment: The combination of changing the parameter name (I should have known better...) and using parentheses around the WaterUsage? declaration seemed to have solved it

Comment: Great! I wish Swift required `self` for property access. Wouldn't have let you get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close! When using the `MemberType[]` syntactic sugar for arrays, the way that you wrote it (`WaterUsage?[]`) actually declares the Array as Optional, as well as the values that it holds. In which case, to assign a value to an index you would need to unwrap the Array first by using:

`usage![hour] = someWaterUsage`

However, if you only want Optional members in the Array (and don't want the Array itself to be optional), then you can fall back to the standard Array declaration:

`var usage = Array<WaterUsage?>(count:24, repeatedValue:nil)`

**edit:**

*I originally offered an alternate syntax as another solution as well:*

`var usage = (WaterUsage?)[](count:24, repeatedValue:nil)`

*...but in doing so, per @Nate's observations it then becomes the case that you need to use unwrapping twice to access the value at a specific index, for example:*

`usage[0]!!.someProperty`

*this is just a shot in the dark, but I think what may be happening in this case is not dissimilar at all to what OP originally tried with declaring the Array using `WaterUsage?[]`*

*that is, when using `(WaterUsage?)[]`, perhaps it is seeing this declaration as an **Array** of **Optional Tuples** holding **Optional WaterUsages**, requiring us then to unwrap the member at the index twice before we can access its properties*

*interesting stuff!*

Comment: There's definitely some Swift bugginess around declaring arrays of Optionals. With your first declaration the resulting type is `WaterUsage??[]`, which means you have to unwrap array members twice before you can access them: `usage[0]!!.someProperty`.

Comment: dude! that is crazy  :)

Comment: actually I just checked, and that is not the case for me at all - if I substitute `String` for `WaterUsage` I don't need to unwrap it at all to access it

Comment: oh weird, I see it now, tried it with an object - strangeness!

Comment: tried everything here (generics, parenthesis, unwrapping) and still got the subscript error